# How to print a message dialog window

Tags: printing, dialog-window

I'm trying to figure out how to print a message dialog without printing the whole notebook.
`FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["PrintDialog"]]` displays the print window (just like selecting file -> 
print but it prints the whole notebook. I have also tried using `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["PrintSelectionDialog"]]` but when the code is run the selected area becomes unselected.

I have solved part of the problem with the following

```
DialogInput[
  DialogNotebook[{Column[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}], 
      Row[{Button["print", 
         DialogReturn[
          FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["PrintDialog"]]]]}]}]}]];
```

This prints the entire window including the print button as shown.
[image: print output]
This is exactly what I am looking for but without the print button.
Any ideas much appreciated,
Christina

Comment: If you mean a message dialog that you code yourself.  Consider creating a notebook on the fly that you format, size, and configure to operate as a message dialog.  A bit of a heavy handed workaround but that should give you all the flexibility you need.  Easier to answer if you give more a specific example and some code.

Comment: Your question is not too well specified.  I tried to provide a couple of general examples below, but if you will give more context for your problem I will try to be more specific myself.

Comment: I appreciate the update.  I tried to find a solution to print everything but the button but I could not.  Hopefully someone with FrontEnd expertise will be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me from your question how you want to use this operation.  If you create a `Button` with this code you should be able to click the button to print a selected block of code.

```
Button["Print Selection",
  FrontEndTokenExecute @ "PrintSelectionDialog"
]
```

If you want to perform this operation programmatically you need to control the selection with e.g. [`SelectionMove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SelectionMove.html).

```
(
 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell];
 FrontEndTokenExecute @ "PrintSelectionDialog"
)
```

You can move the selection to a different Cell or Notebook if needed.  In addition to the documentation for `SelectionMove` read:  [Manipulating Notebooks from the Kernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooksFromTheKernel.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I created a button to execute NotebookPrint[CreateDocument[stuff to be printed]]

Comment: @Christina you're welcome; I'm sorry I didn't have something more specific for you, but I'm glad you found something that works for your application.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
PrintMessage[expr_] := NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[],
       Cell[RawBoxes@ToBoxes[expr,StandardForm],"Output"]]
```

Comment: Since Mr.Wizard's answer was accepted with the fact it does something different than yours, I think your answer isn't on topic. But I agree the question itself may be vague.

Comment: True, but the key idea was "how to print a message dialog", which wasn't really answered.

Comment: +1 Not sure what the OP was really looking for, but when I searched for writing to the Message window, this answer came up, and that's what *I* was looking for.